# Laravel Eloquent using where pattern

Tags: php, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have this PostgreSQL query which checks a value if it matches one of the string pattern in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'value' LIKE column
```

I want to do this in Laravel 5.1 using Eloquent. But doing something like :

```
$prefix = 'value';
Model::where($prefix, 'LIKE', column)->firstOrFail();
```

returns an error. Apparently the first argument of where ($prefix) will always be treated as column name in Laravel (put between double quotes). Is there anyway to fix this or any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw:

```
Model::whereRaw("'{$prefix}' LIKE column")->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

```
Model::where($prefix, 'LIKE', "'%' || column_name || '%'")->firstOrFail();
```

**With:**

```
Model::where('.$prefix.', 'LIKE', "'%' || column_name || '%'")->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: still getting error... now i got `zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ..." where "table"."deleted_at" is null and ""."$prefi...
^ (SQL: select * from "table" where "table"."deleted_at" is null and ""."$prefix"."" LIKE '%' || column_name || '%' limit 1)`